# Why won't this select open up?

Tags: html, select

I have a very simple select drop down. In Chrome, it doesn't drop down. The code itself works fine, and the drop down works in Safari, but for some reason it won't open in Chrome. Here is the HTML:

```
<select name="pellet_credit" class="item_discount">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

It should be pretty simple. It's a dropdown... Here's a screenshot of the select, selected, but not open:
[image]

--- edit ---

This is a jsfiddle with the full source included. The dropdown works for me in the jsfiddle view, but not on the actual site.

http://jsfiddle.net/HSYvf/

--- edit ---

Other drop downs on the page work fine.

Comment: That works for me in Chrome. What version are you using?

Comment: Hello, problem should be somewhere else, this code works fine in Chrome, be more precise or give more code please.

Comment: It works fine for me as well by itself. However, this snippet on the great page doesn't work. I'll paste more of it

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is the snippet. Does the control get disabled at some point?

Comment: @Pekka not that I know of. It works in other browsers too.

Comment: This is really a lot of code... I don't think anyone wants to go through it and spot a (maybe) tiny mistake. Use a proper editor or IDE that does some HTML and JavaScript validation.

Comment: @Felix I do. I was just responding to the request to see more code.

Comment: Yep..works fine in Chrome and FF for me. Problem must be somewhere else...perhaps in the CSS or JS. Inspect the element in FF w/ Firebug and see what styles are applied to it.

Comment: FF would do this if you surrownd the `select` in a `label` (at time of commenting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Validate your HTML to make sure there aren't extraneous closing/end tags. Make sure you aren't hiding the options through CSS as well.

Comment: I'd also look for some stray javascript getting in the way of click events

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Firefox and Chrome and due to the `z-index` of the form being `-1`.

When changed the `z-index`, it worked fine.

Comment: What worked for you might not work for others. Be sure what you suggest works for the man who posted the question before you give an answer!

Comment: You have saved me a lot of time, have gave me a really good explanation and  have are increase my awareness on basic conceptions of HTML world. All at once in a short answer. In my case, the select element had a large zIndex. This was generating instability on rendering. Any way, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I put a `<select>` inside a jQuery .sortable() element.  I copied this code right off the jQuery website, and the .disableSelection() method call killed my `<select>`.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Once I removed the `.disableSelection();` (which oddly enough they've deprecated...) everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

We had a crazy problem when we were developing a client/server programming language which had a listbox. Although INPUT worked the listbox didn't. We have mouse tracking on it and by a bug the $(window).mousedown... was being enabled by default.

We were able to track the problem with this page: https://hackernoon.com/finding-that-pesky-listener-thats-hijacking-your-event-javascript-b590593f2a83

Just in case the above page disappears:

In Chrome (possibly other Chromium flavours [works on Opera too]):

1. Right click on element.
2. Click 'Inspect...'
3. When the 'Elements' are shown, the right panel will have [Styles][Computed][Event Listeners] (tabs). Click on 'Event Listeners'.
4. Look for 'mouseup', 'mousedown', 'keyup', etc and expand what you suspect and remove it to see if that fixes the problem (debug).
5. Change the code.

What we did was change the 'return false' to 'return true' in our code.

Comment: This is was very helpful in helping me source an issue with some html components not functioning correctly in a map popup, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set a value for your options

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

you can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: Had that before. It was being generated by php, but i stripped it down and it still had problems.

Answer (score 1):

what ended up happening to me that caused me to be on this page is that display was set to display:none; on the option elements

solution:

$(yourdropdown).children().show();

Answer (score 1):

To debug such issues try removing all attributes from the html and add them one at a time to find out what is causing the issue.
For example, the snippet below does not work as needed.

```html
<select size="10">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

Removing the size attribute fixes it

```html
<select >
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer just to call out the comment by @Agos in the selected answer. Check if you have  event handling code (mousedown, click, etc.) that might be stealing the events from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had included class names in the `id` declaration.

For future audience, notice in particular if your select element is inconsistent with the surrounding form styles.  This is a likely clue that a class isn't being applied correctly, and you may have accidentally placed it in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else here reading different situations, mine didn't open-up the select options because I had a class on the `select` element which applied a style like this:

```css
.class:readonly {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

So I had to override it with `pointer-events: auto !important;` to fix the problem.